# How to determine infrared protocol using PIC16?

Tags: pic, infrared, protocol

I am trying to determine the IR protocol used in a [Gree](http://www.gree.com.cn/english/) room air conditioner [remote control](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxEk8XZN3FftbUEwb3AxS1dsck0/edit?usp=sharing). I connected the output of the original IR receiver to pin RA5 of a [PIC16F73](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/30325b.pdf) and used the following code to measure the time periods of the high and low pulses.

```
while(1)
{
    while(PORTAbits.RA5 == 1) //Wait for a low edge.
    {
        ;
    }
    T1CONbits.TMR1ON = 0; //Turn off Timer 1.
    duration[durationCounter] = TMR1; //Record duration of pulse in array 'duration'.
    TMR1 = 0; //Reset Timer 1.
    durationCounter++;
    T1CONbits.TMR1ON = 1;
    lowEdges++;
    while(PORTAbits.RA5 == 0) //Wait for next high edge.
    {
        ;
    }
    T1CONbits.TMR1ON = 0; //Similarly for low edge.
    duration[durationCounter] = TMR1;
    TMR1 = 0;
    durationCounter++;
    T1CONbits.TMR1ON = 1;
    highEdges++;
}
```

I've entered the data in [this excel file](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxEk8XZN3FftTS1QbnptZzlLdUU/edit?usp=sharing). But the pulse widths seem to vary randomly and make no sense to me. I've checked articles on the NEC, RC-5 etc. protocols but none seems to match this data. Is the program inadequate to capture the data?

Comment: If what you want to do is automate the system the actual protocol is not required. Just 'record' the signal for each command you need and then retransmit the signal as you require.

Comment: @JImDearden - Sorry if it sounds like that but that's not the intention. I'm trying to keep something compatible with the existing remote control. Besides, as it appears, each button press transmits the entire 'state' of the air conditioner like mode, fan speed, temperature setting and even the current time and ON/OFF timers. And isolating each command from the stream is turning out to be a task now. Thanks anyways. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two questions, how to interpret the IR protocol and how to make a logic analyzer to capture samples of the protocol.

To guess the protocol, look around on the net.  You might find where someone has already figured it out.  These things are usually not deliberately obfuscated, but inferring the protocol just from a bunch of samples can be tricky.  Most likely each packet starts with a burst of alternating high/low, called the *preamble*.  This is intended to let the data slicer in the receiver settle.  Then there will be something with different timing to mark the start of the packet.  This is necessary because the assumption is that some of the preamble is not received.

After that there are a lot of choices.  Some use manchester encoding, and some use 1/3 and 2/3 pulse lengths to signify 1 and 0.  I've seen some that use chunks of 4 bits to transmit decimal or hex digits, usualy followed by a checksum digit.

Capture a few representative packets with a logic analyzer or even a scope.  With a scope you will probably have to capture a whole packet in pieces and glue them back together manually.

As for making your own logic analyzer, that's a distraction that should be avoided if possible.  If I really had to do this with a PIC, I'd at least use the CCP module in capture mode, then report the time between edges over the UART or something, then save the data in maybe a CSV file so you can use off the shelf tools to look at it in detail later.  You can then even test receiving algorithms on your computer by having them process the CSV file.

Comment: Ah yes... should've put them separately. I found this (http://www.pcbheaven.com/userpages/Reverse_Engineering_Fidji_Air_Condition_IR_Protocol/) which is exactly what I'm trying to do but this author has got some very plausible results unlike what I am getting E.g. (in ms): 9.8,3.5 (Preamble), 5.125, 0.75, 6.375, 0.75, 4, 0.75... It could be chunks of four bits decimal yes! I have an old scope but doesn't seem to be for the job so I'm left with a PIC :-). Had considered the CCP but it only captures either rising or falling edges. Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: @Sohail: A CCP module captures only one edge, but that can be flipped each capture by the firmware.

Comment: Clever!! Or is it commonplace? :-) But the problem was a little 0.1uF ceramic capacitor that I had connected across the IR receiver output. It was messing up the signals. The numbers are believable now. :-) And I am not allowed to thank you :-P

Comment: @Sohail: Instead of thanking, we upvote and/or accept here.